# SQL Select all rows starting with numbers from 0-9

Tags: sql, sqlite

I use SQlite to select rows starting with a certain letter, eg:a, b, c.

```
SELECT title FROM dictionary WHERE title LIKE 'a%' ORDER BY title ASC
SELECT title FROM dictionary WHERE title LIKE 'b%' ORDER BY title ASC
SELECT title FROM dictionary WHERE title LIKE 'c%' ORDER BY title ASC
...
```

But I also want to select all titles starting with a number from 0-9, something like that LIKE '0-9%'.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can tidy up your original LIKE statements by adding OR:

```
SELECT title FROM dictionary WHERE title LIKE 'a%' OR name like '%b' OR name like '%c' ORDER BY title ASC.
```

To answer your problem you can use a regex as the title is string based.

```
WHERE title regexp '^[0-9]+'
```

OR

```
WHERE (LEFT(title, 1) IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'))
```

You can also try substring and numeric function:

```
WHERE ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(VAL, 1, 1))
```

**NOT TESTED** but will help you think on how to get this resolved

Comment: Is too complicated to use the current function REGEX, the function must be called in a specific way. https://sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_2_2

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

**SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourColumn regexp '^[0-9]+'**

Answer (score 1):

Try to use regexp

```
SELECT title FROM dictionary WHERE title regexp '^[0-9]+';
```